# What mean if installation files is bigger then program itself?

Tags: installation, virus

What mean if installation files is bigger then program itself, does it mean virus is inside installation files?
For example, installation files has 15GB and installed program at local disc C only 7GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could mean anything.

The program could have 32-bit and 64-bit versions and only one gets installed.

The program could have lots of optional parts that are not installed.

The installer could contain a lot of dependencies such as libraries and other programs that get installed elsewhere in the system.

If you downloaded the installer from the company that created it then it is unlikely to have malware or a virus in it. You should only download things from places you trust.